# The purpose of wrapping headers with #ifdef _cplusplus

Tags: c++, macros

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
   #include headerfile.h
#endif
```

I understand the concept behind this, though I don't exactly understand why it's needed.

If the purpose is to prevent "mangling" of headers when the code isn't compiled in C++:

-how is the code compiled if not in C++?

-how would the code continue to function without that header?

And tangentially:

-what circumstances would require this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- how is the code compiled if not in C++?

With C.

- how would the code continue to function without that header?

That's why the header is included. If it would compile and work without the header with a C++ compiler, the `#ifdef` would be pretty pointless.

- what circumstances would require this?

They may just bring in stuff needed when compiling with a C++ compiler. Maybe a debug macro needs to use `std::cerr`, then that header may include `<iostream>`. It could have millions of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The usual reason for doing it is to give functions C or C++ linkage:

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include headerfile.h
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If C++ is not defined it would rely on non C++ specific header( possibly written in C)

What circumstance would require this is a good question.

Comment: That seems slightly obvious now that you've said it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is probably dead, but its still very much alive in search engines so I thought I would post some more detail.  C++ mangles routine names (adds a bunch of characters) when they are compiled.  I don't have the knowledge to tell you why it does that.  I would guess to ensure that routines are uniquely identified among all the namespaces and classes in the program.  Regardless, C does not mangle names.  If you try to include a C header file in your project everything will work great during compilation, but when you link C++ will mangle the names of the routines in the C header file and try to find them in the object file for the C routines.  It won't be able to find them because it expects them to be mangled.

This is most prevalent when you try to use a preexisting C library.  In this case you can't recompile the C code as C++ to restore name mangling.  So you have to tell the C++ compiler to look for C-style routines using 'extern "C"'.  Putting it in the header file isn't necessary, but wherever a C++ compiler finds a declaration of a C routine it will need it.  The header file placement is to avoid repeating yourself.

This can also happen in some IDEs.  But basically results in a C library being linked with a C++ program/library.  If gcc was used to compile it, g++ will have trouble figuring it out.